# jessie PIXEL and file copy

Tags: pixel, file

While I can move files using drag / drop in PIXEL, how do I copy a file to a new folder and leave the original in place. With Windows you just hold CTRL down. Doesn't work in PIXEL. Are there 'instructions' for this anywhere?

Mike

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are asking how to copy files in `PCManFM` which is the default File Manager in the latest Raspbian GUI. (`PIXEL` is the name of the Desktop Manager “Pi Improved Xwindows Environment, Lightweight”.)

You can copy files with the `Edit/Copy` and `Edit/Paste` Menu items, more conveniently using `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V` shortcut keys, which are the same as Windows.

There are other File Managers, and you can more conveniently copy files in the terminal using `cp source_file target_file`.

Comment: Yes, I did mean the 'File manager' that comes with the PIXEL GUI. Does that mean I can't just drag / drop a file from one folder to another as a 'copy' as in Windows? It does a 'move' OK. I know about the 'Terminal' method but you can't say this is 'more convenient' when it means a load of typing. Does ctrl+C and ctrl+V work on the file icons or on the file content?

Comment: The shortcuts should work most places. Why not try it. I rarely use GUI and never dragon-droppings, so can't say, but I always found having to use the mouse **AND** keyboard the worst of both worlds. There is very little documentation.